# Custom Modal Dialog Box in Browser back in Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, location, angular5

Suppose my current route is **/transact/orders** and is in Order summary view, What I want to do is to open a  custom dialog which gives the option to **add to cart** or **cancel**  button when he/she presses browser back button of the browser.If user press **add to cart** button it goes to the cart or else the browser back button functionality will happen. Currently, I am using Angular 5.2.I would like to know if it is possible with **LocationStrategy**.I searched but could not get a proper example of it.Can anybody explain with proper example?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to Location events anywhere you want to do actions on back button pressed:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';     
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = <Subscription>  this.location.subscribe( () => {
        // your code here
} );
}

ngOnDestroy() {

    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe in OnDestroy.  
EDIT: location should be type Location, not LocationStrategy